# Showing user's comments on posts in Django

Tags: django

I am adding a comment section for my posts in a blog, I reached to the part where I can add new comments and get it saved in the db and I can view them in the admin, but I am stuck to showing the username and the comment in the comment section, I have to go the admin and choose the name of the user and the blog name to appear in the page, how do i link them together

Here is the Models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

Here is the views.py:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-id')
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = self.request.POST.get('content')
                comment = Comment.objects.create(
                    post=post, user=request.user, content=content)
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("post_detail.html")
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        context["comments"] = comments
        context["comment_form"] = comment_form
        return context


class PostCommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content', ]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('score:post-detail')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            post.save()
        print(args, kwargs, request.POST)
        return redirect('score:post-detail', slug=kwargs['slug'])
```

here is the template

```
            <form action={% url 'score:post-comment' post.slug %} method="post" class="comment-form" action=".">
            {% comment %} <form method="post" class="comment-form" action="."> {% endcomment %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ comment_form.as_p }}
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" disabled> You must be Logged in to Comment
            {% endif %}
            </form>
```

here is the form

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(label="", widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text goes here!!!', 'rows': '4', 'cols': '50'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('content',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CreateView` is defined to remove most of the boilplate code, so you should not reimplement that in the `post` method, but let the `CreateView` do its work.

What you here should do is override the [**`.form_valid(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) and the [**`.form_invalid(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_invalid), and the [**`.get_success_url(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url) to redirect to the proper view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse

class PostCommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = post
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('score:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))
```